# Question on second order partial differentiation involving chain rules from Schaum's Calculus 5ed

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I'm stuck on the below exercise which is in Schaum's calculus 5ed chapter 49 on total differentiation:

If $z$ = $\phi(u,v)$ where $u=f(x,y)$ and $v=g(x,y)$, and if $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$, show that
$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} = \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial y^2} = 0$

I tried evaluating the second order partial derivatives of $\phi$ w.r.t $x$ and $y$ and using the derived expressions to solve for $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$ etc but didn't come out to the result so not sure if I've made an algebraic mistake or my method is wrong somehow. Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the information about $z=\phi(u,v)$ is completely redundant; it simply adds to the confusion. If you assume $u,v$ are $C^2$ functions, then this statement follows immediately from the equality of mixed partials and the given hypotheses on the first derivatives:
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2} + \dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2} &=
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right) 
+ \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right) \tag{by definition}\\
&= \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}\right) 
+ \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(-\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right) \tag{by hypothesis} \\
&= \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}\right) 
- \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}\right) \tag{equality of mixed partials} \\
&= 0
\end{align}
A similar proof holds for showing $v$ is harmonic.

Comment: Thanks very much. I upvoted but as my reputation is low it doesn't show.